# Concerns regarding a password manager web app

Tags: web-browser, password-management, javascript, scrypt

I've written a password manager in JavaScript. It works in a browser.
[Try it out](https://markonius.gitlab.io/ozvena/ozvena.html)

Are there any fundamental issues with the concept of a web based password manager?
Should I be concerned if hashes linger in memory longer than they should or is there some fundamental issue with how browsers work that makes this system insecure?

[Here is the main source file](https://gitlab.com/markonius/ozvena/blob/master/public/ozvena.js), if you want to take a closer look.

EDIT: To clarify, this app runs 100% locally, has no external dependencies and doesn't store any information except some settings in a cookie if you want to.
This is a deterministic, hashing password manager.

EDIT 2, to be extra specific: If I store user input in a variable, and the resulting hash in another variable, how plausible is the threat of that information leaking?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as _too broad_. Usually code analysis is out of topic, and analyzing an entire password manager is too broad.

Comment: I am not asking a code review, but I've posted the app and the code for context and if someone wants to take a look. My question is in the second paragraph, if you still think it is too broad, I can make efforts to reword it.

Comment: a) Legal issues, big ones, at least for the users. While there will be differences for different countries, I just thought about my 10 most frequently used passwords, and in all cases there are requirements not to add them to such services. Partially it could get me into jail. b) "Really??" In times of large-scale surveillance by many countries and companies too, this is NOT a good idea. At least if the passwords protect something which is worth the effort to enter a password. And no, your web server will never be as secure as my brain.

Comment: c) Yes, there is an issue with browsers: They are evidently among the most insecure pieces of software - partially because of their complexity nowadays, and partially because the amount of people that are interested in holes  (and look for them).because it's *the* way to infect many people easily. Passwords are used for more things than websites - for such cases adding a browser to the mix weakens everything.

Comment: Have a look at Lastpass, they do exactly what you describe. And they seem to be quite successful in business (although there is a free plan too).

Comment: @MackThax if your real questions are in the 2nd paragraph, and you are not looking for a review, then your answers are really easily researched. Debates have been raging for *years* on the security of web-based password managers with lots of study on the weaknesses of browsers.

Comment: @Marcel It seems that LastPass works as an extension instead of a web page, but it should be simillar enough.

Comment: @schroeder Could you point me in some direction? My searches lead to forum posts and debates like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone discovers a vulnerability in a browser that lets an attacker read data across web page/tab boundaries then there's a risk that they'll be able to extract information from it.

A browser is essentially a container for applications so all those security implications apply.

Comment: How plausible is this threat? Is the possibility of someone reading values stored in variables is JS any greater than the possibility of someone reading another application's memory?

Comment: Yes, because usually you have multiple tabs open and you have little control over what exactly is being run because web pages have dozens of dependencies, load ads, run flash, render things, and there's just so much running in a web page you have no control over. You have much more control over what applications you run (and install) on your local computer than you have control over what your browser is running. Also, depending on the browser... tabs and JS reside in the same memory region and are not separated whereas different applications at least have their own address space.